# Some Kubernetes traffic ignoring VLAN

Tags: linux-networking, vlan, kubernetes

I have a small Kubernetes cluster that I set up using `kubeadm`. My servers are connected via a VLAN, which my provider lets me add my servers into.

The VLAN adds a network adapter (`ens6`), which I created a virtual adapter (`veth0`) on, that assigns each server an IP on my VLAN.

The relevant `netcfg` looks like this:

```
vlans:
  veth0:
    id: 0
    link: ens6
    addresses: [10.96.0.1/24]
```

Server 01 has the IP 10.96.0.1, Server 02 has the IP 10.96.0.2.

Inspecting traffic with `bmon`, I see some traffic on the `veth0` interface between the servers in the cluster.

```
RX (S01)     TX (S01)
 4.77GiB     60.28GiB

RX (S02)     TX (S02)
59.70GiB      5.48GiB
```

Looking at my public LAN interface (`ens3`), I see a suspiciously high amount of traffic for my cluster which has hardly any applications deployed on it:

```
RX (S01)     TX (S01)
 46.60GiB    304.84GiB

RX (S02)     TX (S02)
309.69GiB     40.86GiB
```

I bootstrapped the cluster with this command `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr 10.98.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=10.96.0.1 --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=<public ip for remote kubeadm>`. The other server joined using a VLAN IP as well.

Inspecting `ens3` using `nethogs` on both servers I am seeing external traffic from `kubelet` and `kube-apiserver`.

**How can I verify both nodes are talking over the VLAN and how can I best debug where this excess network traffic is coming from? How can I full restrict cluster traffic to the virtual LAN?**

Comment: those two servers has the same ip? Server 01 has the IP 10.96.0.1, Server 02 has the IP 10.96.0.1

Comment: @c4f4t0r Good catch! No Server 1 has .01 and Server 2 has .02

Answer (score 0):

- You can verify the incoming traffic to see if they have  `VLAN`  tags by using  `tcpdump`  with the  `-e and vlan`  option.
  This will show the details of the  `VLAN`  header:

```
# tcpdump -i eno1 -nn -e  vlan
To capture the issue live.
```

or

```
# tcpdump -i eno1 -nn -e  vlan -w /tmp/vlan.pcap
To write to the capture to a file.
```

Comment: I don't have a `bond0` interface. Should I capture for `veth0` or `ens3`?

Comment: tcpdump -i any -nn -e  vlan -w /tmp/vlan.pcap

Comment: after -i you use name of interface which you tried to check it could be any for all